# How to Delete or Grab specific texts inside a file

Tags: linux

Linux Centos 6-64

`File1.txt` has several lines in this format:

```
/Text1/Text2/Text3:Text4
```

How to do to have file `Result.txt` to be with all lines as follows?

```
Text2;Text4
```

PS: the `:` transforms into `;`.

I thought of two ways of doing this:

1. It would be OK to delete `/Text1/` and delete `/Text3` and change `:` by `;`.
2. Or read what's between 2nd and 3rd `/` as `Text2` then read what's after `:` which is `Text4` and do `;Text4`.

So as final result the file `Result.txt` would have

```
Text2;Text4
```

Either way would work, better the one that works faster.

PS: The texts may have spaces, symbols and points inside, but the original separators from the texts are always `/` `/` `/` `:` which don't appear anywhere else inside the texts.

This to be done in all lines of `File.txt`.

---

Files:

`File1.txt`

```
/Soccer.Teacher/Michael.John/Group1:monday-friday - 14h to 16h
/Basketball.Teacher/Susana.Stevens/Group2:tuesday-thursday-3pm-to-5pm
/Tennis.Teacher/Josh.Karen/Group3:monday-wednesday-5pm_to_7pm
```

etc.

`Result.txt` to be:

```
Michael.John:monday-friday - 14:00 to 16:00
Susana.Stevens:tuesday-thursday-3pm-to-5pm
Josh.Karen:monday-wednesday-5pm_to_7pm
```

etc.

Comment: combination of `grep` and  `sed` with interesting regex (regular expression). - I don't know enough regex to do what you want, but that should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The texts may have spaces, symbols and points inside, but the original separators from the texts are always `/` `/` `/` `:` which don't appear anywhere else inside the texts.

<strike>Not true. You gave an example with `14:00 to 16:00`. For a moment let's suppose it's true.</strike> This allows a straightforward approach:

```
tr ':' '/' | cut -d '/' --output-delimiter=';' -f 3,5
```

`tr` unifies delimiters, then `cut` picks the right fields.

Notes:

- `--output-delimiter` is not required by POSIX. If your `cut` doesn't support it, this is the alternative:

  ```
  tr ':' '/' | cut -d '/' -f 3,5 | tr '/' ';'
  ```

  Note we cannot use `tr ':' ';'` as the first command in the pipe (which would simplify the rest) because you don't guarantee that `;` doesn't appear in the input (`cut` will get confused if it does).
- `cut` takes fields 3 and 5 (not 2 and 4) because everything before the first separator is already field 1 (empty string in your case).

However, if only the first `:` should be a separator then the command may be:

```
sed 's|:|/|' | cut -d '/' --output-delimiter=';' -f 3,5
```

`sed 's|:|/|'` will replace only the first occurrence of `:` (opposed to `sed 's|:|/|g'` which is equivalent to our original `tr ':' '/'`).

---

In case you are not familiar with a standard way to use such filters with files, this is the right syntax (with `sed` and POSIX-compliant `cut`):

```
< File1.txt sed 's|:|/|' | cut -d '/' -f 3,5 | tr '/' ';' > Result.txt
```

Comment: Hello Kamil, thanks for your notes, I have edited the question to correct 14:00 to 14h and 16:00 to 16h to make sense. Your last command worked perfect here and it has the File1.txt and the Result.txt. Have voted up for your reply. Thanks

Comment: Hello Kamil, one question please if allowed still in this post. If there are random quantity of texts and want only as result.txt what is in position Text2, the ; separation, and then whatever comes after the : how could this final command you posted be adapted? Example: /Text1/Text2/Text3/Text4:Text5 or /Text1/Text2/Text3/Text4/Text5:Text6 or /Text1/Text2/Text3/Text4/Text5/Text6:Text7 etc. For result to always be Text2;whatisafterthe:  Thanks

Comment: @Joao `sed 's|:|/|' | awk -F '/' '{print $3";"$NF}'`

Answer (score 2):

[`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) does that:

```
echo '/Text1/Text2/Text3:Text4' | sed -E 's/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\2;\4/'
```

- `-E` use extended regular expressions
- `\/` use escape charachter to spesific `/` char
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` define let say *word Pattern* region.
- `\2;\4` accessing to second and forth region parts.

according to your last edition:

```
sed -E 's/\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/:]+):([^/]+)$/\2;\4/' FileName
```

Comment: Hello Hossein, in this command it is not getting File1.txt and transforming into Result.txt. Texts1,2,3,4 change in each line of the file, is not something fixed. Result to be printed in new file Result.txt. What else could I add there to achieve this result? Thanks

Comment: ok please, some more lines of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest/fastest solution, but gets the job done and is easy to understand:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    echo -n "$line" | cut -d "/" -f 3 | tr -d $'\n'
    echo -n ";"
    echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 2
done < "File1.txt"
```

`-n` for the first two `echo`s is important so it's all in one line.

Since your version of `cut` doesn't support `-z` the `| tr -d $'\n'` is needed to remove cut's trailing newline.

Comment: Hello Confetti, thanks for replying, when I use your code it says this: "cut: invalid option -- 'z'
Try `cut --help' for more information."

Comment: Which operating system are you on? What's `cut --version`?

Comment: version 8.4 using on centos 6-64

Comment: Hello Confetti, it works now, thank you. One question, is it possible that this gets into only 1 line command instead of 5? Thanks

Comment: `while read -r line; do echo -n "$line" | cut -d "/" -f 3 | tr -d $'\n' && echo -n ";" && echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 2; done < "File1.txt"` :)